# Angular2 show only one li element data on click

Tags: angular

I have slider with 8 elements thats reperesent models. Content of class info should be hidden by default. I want to make visible info content on click, but for that one model. Li elements have width 200px and height 200px ang it have background-image. How to make it optimally?

Mycode:

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li 
        class="slider__model"
        *ngFor="
            let model of femaleModels | slice:this.bottomLimit:this.topLimit;
            let i = index;"
    >
        <div class="info" (click)="toggleData();"">
            <div class="model__content"></div>
            <div class="model__text">
                {{ model.name | uppercase}}, {{model.dateOfBirth }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `this` in *template*: `let model of femaleModels | slice: bottomLimit: topLimit; let i = index;">`

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: I should add that, li element have width 200px and height 200px ang it have background-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to each model object, and that property can be `visible` and default to `false`.

On hover, or on click, you can call a function `toggleVisibility(i)`, passing the index of the item. In the function, you can do `this.models[i].visible = !this.models[i].visible` which toggles the visiblity.

In your loop items, add `[class.visible]="model.visible"`. Now every time you click a model, it adds visible class. When you click again it removes visible class. Handle the visible class accordingly in your css.

Example:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let model of models; let i = index" 
            [class.visible]="model.visible"
            (click)="toggleVisibility(i)">
            {{model.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
`
})
export class MyComponent {
    models: any[] = [
        {name:'Foo',visible:false},
        {name:'Foo',visible:false},
        {name:'Foo',visible:false}
    ];

    toggleVisibility(index: number) {
        this.models[i].visible = !this.models[i].visible;
    }
}
```

To get the same effect without adding a `visible` property, you could do the following (not tested, you may have to modify it a bit):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let model of models" (click)="toggleVisibility($event)">
            {{model.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
`
})
export class MyComponent {
    models: any[] = [
        {name:'Foo'},
        {name:'Foo'},
        {name:'Foo'}
    ];

    toggleVisibility(event: any) {
        event.target.classList.toggle('visible');
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point. Is there a way to get this effect and avoid new value 'visible' in model obejct?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: It should work. Play around with it a bit. `event.target` is the element you are clicking on, so try `classList.has`, `classList.add`, and so on. That will solve your problem. Let me know if you have any problems.